# How to enable postman settings for follow authorization Header and follow original HTTP methods in Python - Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

So we have a API endpoint that require following settings turned on in Postman :

[image]

I would like to know if there's a way to enable these settings as some params in Robot Framework. Current when we try to request this endpoint we end up getting 401 Status Code. Tried to work with `allow_redirect=true` but it gives the same result as well.

Is there a way in which this can be automated using robot framework and any of the associated libraries ?

This is how the robot file looks :

```
*** Keywords ***    
Example POST Request
        ${api_requestbody}=        User Fetches Json Node Value From Json              ${test_data}                       $.request
        ${response}=    Custom Post Request    https://url.example.com     ${access_token[0]}              {api_requestbody}
        Log    ${response.status_code}
        Log    ${response.text}
    
    
    Custom Post Request
        [Arguments]    ${url}    ${authorization}    ${payload}
        ${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${authorization}
        ${response}=        POST            ${url}          json=${payload}         headers=${headers}         allow_redirects=false
        Delete All Sessions
        [Return]    ${response}
```

Comment: It maybe tricky as RequestLibrary is based on requests which isn't doing it due to security reasons https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2949